# how to pass value from tableviewController to uiviewcontroller after selecting the row

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

I have the code below : where Cell new is Custom cell which has array which has object at index when user selects a row which has to be transfered to anothe uiviewcontroller to display that msg But I am unable to do that.

by doing this : I get an error 
**Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'UILabel *'**

```
VC2.DisplayMsg.text = cell.textLabel;
```

displayMsg is a label in uiviewcontroller where the text has to be displayed.Where Am I going wrong?

Please help me out or suggest any other way to transfer value from navigational uitableviwController to another viewcontroller on selecting the row and displaying the message in that uiviewController.Please help me out.I appreciate a great deal.

Thanks in Advance.

Complete code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


Cellnew *cell = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


      ViewControllerDisplayMsg *VC2 = [[ViewControllerDisplayMsg alloc] init];

VC2.DisplayMsgtext = cell.textLabel.text;


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"displayMsgSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

}
```

The error :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString textLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Two issues: First, you shouldn't refer to the controls in your destination controller (e.g. `VC2.DisplayMsg.text`), as they have not been created by the time `prepareForSegue` is running. Second, you are referencing the cell's `textLabel` control, not its `text` property. I think you meant `cell.textLabel.text`, not `cell.textLabel`.

Comment: Hello Rob Sir .I am currently stuck in the implementation of uitableviewcontroller .This is the first time.I have no clue how to proceed after didSelect method .So far I have created custom cell which loads via json.So after that it should display msg pertaining to the row clicked in the next view.I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Hello Rob can you refer any link for didselect to uiviewcontroller with data (storyboard).It would help me a great deal.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a `NSString`  property in other `viewController` and first assign the value from your table to this string and finally in your viewController's viewDidLoad method you can assign this string to the label text.  It is good idea to define your Other Controller as a property to your FirstController.

You should keep the graphical elements updated within the class because this corresponding class or controller is responsible to show  the graphical elements & values.

**YourTableViewController.h**

```
@class SecondViewController;

@property(strong,nonatomic)SecondViewController secondVC;
```

**YourTableViewController.m**

```
self.secondVC=[SecondViewContrlller alloc]initwithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
self.secondVC.stringValue= cell.textLabel.text;
```

**YourOtherViewController.h**

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *stringValue;
```

**YourOtherViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

self.displayMsg.text=self.stringValue;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir I have implemented the above code ,the line : self.secondVC=[SecondViewContrlller alloc]initwithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; is supposed to be storyboard how do I do that ?

Comment: You are welcome, have you solved your issue?

Comment: No I have not .I am still stuck here :**VC2 = [[ViewControllerDisplayMsg alloc] init];**       **VC2.DisplayMsgtext = cell.textLabel.text;
    
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"displayMessage" sender:self];**       cause exception: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString textLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Comment: Could you post the code and error in your question?

Comment: I have updated the complete code with error.

Comment: What is DisplayMsgtext in your code? please post the code how you defining these strings.

Comment: set the breakpointer and also try to print out the value of the `cell.textLabel.text` and see what it shows for result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26471/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-nsgulliver)

Answer (score 1):

Take a NSString property in your UIViewController, say DisplayMsg:
then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
VC2.DisplayMsg=cell.textLabel.text;
```

Comment: Thanks Ken for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

This code will help you

Comment: Hello Sir .What does the object contain string ? and how do I retrieve that from another controller? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Created sample name for the method, can put your own

Comment: I am getting an error here : ViewControllerDisplayMsg *VC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"displayMessage"];
//

Comment: doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'displayMessage'